# How does reverse string code work?

Tags: java, string, reverse

can anyone explain how does this program work.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String input ="***NGuyen**Van******A*******";
    String result ="";
    for( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++)
    {

            result =  input.charAt(i) + result ;

        }


    System.out.println(result);
```

}}

The output will be

```
*******A******naV**neyuGN***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is getting the characters from left to right (low to high, 0 to length)

It is appending the characters from right to left.

that reverses them.

```
1 2 3
| | |
\ | /
  X
/ | \
3 2 1
```

First time through the loop, it takes '1' and puts it in the string.

Second time through the loop, it takes '2' and puts it in the string to the left of '1'

Thirst time through the loop, it takes '3' and puts it to the left of '2' and '1'.

When I say "it takes" I'm referring to the code: `input.charAt(i)`

Note that the 'i' gets bigger each time through the loop because of the `i++`

Comment: Thank you , I got the idea now, but I want to know how does it work with the loop  to change them from low to high  left to right as what you explained.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a badly written program that constantly creates new (immutable) `String` objects while iterating over the characters of `input` from left to right, each time prepending the character to `result`.  This is done by the code `input.charAt(i) + result` which puts the character in front of the previous result.

A better implementation would use a `StringBuilder` (which is mutable) to avoid excessive `String` creation.

Like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "***NGuyen**Van******A*******";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String result;
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        builder.append(input.charAt(i));
    }
    result = builder.toString();

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: I did it is that what you meant

Comment: I did it is that what you meant "      StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder("***NGuyen**Van******A******* ");       "      it's my first time using it since I still beginner in programing . Thanks.

Comment: No that is not what I meant, see the example I added to the answer.  The result will be the same, only better in terms of performance and memory usage (although it is a simple program of course).

Comment: Thank you very mush. I will look for "builder" more now since it's important for memory .

Comment: The difference in this solution and OP's original, beside `StringBuilder`, is that it takes the characters out of the original string from right to left and adds them from left to right. Either direction of taking characters out of the source string will work.

Comment: Important to note is that when using the `+` operator for Strings/chars, the compiler actually generates a `StringBuilder` for that operation, then converts the result into a `String`.  So in a loop for a `String` with 100 characters, it will create 100 `StringBuilders` and 100 `Strings` while you need just 1 of each.